# how to we can search JSON data from the Django admin?

Tags: django

how to we can search and filter JSON data from the Django admin and how can we pass the JSON key in search list in the admin.py file during model registration??
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/YMKxO.png)

In this admin page how can we use search and filter functionality on json field??
I am using django with mongodb

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Answer (score 0):

`search_fields = ('<fieldname>__<jsonkey>',)`

Comment: Remember that Stack Overflow isn't just intended to solve the immediate problem, but also to help future readers find solutions to similar problems, which requires understanding the underlying code. This is especially important for members of our community who are beginners, and not familiar with the syntax. Given that, **can you [edit] your answer to include an explanation of what you're doing** and why you believe it is the best approach?